# VB.NET Garbage Collection for Image opened with Image.FromFile

Tags: .net, vb.net, garbage-collection

Please consider this code:

```
Public Class MyOwnClass
    Public Property MyString As String

    Public Property MyImage As Image
End Class

Dim MyList As New List(Of MyOwnClass)

Public Sub Add()
    MyList.Add(New MyOwnClass With {.MyString = "MyString", .MyImage = Image.FromFile("C:\MyPath\MyPic.png")})
End Sub

Public Sub Clear()
    MyList = Nothing
End Sub
```

Where I define a class with a reference to an Image, a List of my class.

The first `Sub` adds an item to the list and my question is about the second `Sub`:
is nullifying the reference to the list enough to make the garbage collector to wipe out both my class instance and the referenced image within?

They all look managed resources to me, so my answer would be "Of course it is!", but can't be sure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, an image is not a managed resource. It implements IDisposable so you need to Dispose it, otherwise you will get GDI+ errors later in your program.

Because Image is IDisposable you need to make your own class IDisposable. Use the common pattern to add a Finalizer to your MyOwnClass to make sure that you properly dispose of the image. I dont do VB, but here is the general idea in C#

```
public class MyOwnClass : IDisposable
{
    public Image MyImage {get;set;}
    private bool disposed = false;
    private bool disposing = false;
    ~MyOwnClass()
    {
        this.dispose();
    }
    private void dispose()
    {
        if(! disposed && ! disposing)
        {
            disposing = true;
            if(this.MyImage != null) this.MyImage.Dispose();
            this.MyImage = null;
        }
        disposed = true;

    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SupressFinalizer(this);
        this.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew it couldn't be that easy! But after implementing the `IDisposable` interface, nullifying the list is enough or again should I call the Dispose for each element in the list?

Comment: If you null the list all the instances within it will be added to the Finalizer thread - this isn't the best outcome since it will take an indeterminate time (typically a few ms) for their Finalizer code to be called, but becasue you've defined a Finalizer then your image will definitely be disposed safely. A common fault is to implement IDisposable without a Finalizer - this means just nulling the list would leave your Images un-disposed and lead to errors. If you see Dispose() with no ~Finalizer() tell the programmer off !

Comment: Please don't publish source code that uses a finalizer that does absolutely nothing.  We're trying to teach programmers here to stop using finalizers, you are not helping that cause.

Comment: @HansPassant So I should not implement the Finalizer? Without it will I then need to call the Dispose on each item of the list before voiding the reference to it?

Comment: No, it does absolutely nothing.  The Image class already has a finalizer, it does not need any help.  And it already has a Dispose() method as well, that doesn't need any help either.  All that you need to do is call its Dispose() method when you're done using the object.  Like when you empty the List.

Comment: So if I got it right `MyList.Clear()` is all what I need and `MyList = Nothing` wouldn't be enough to mark the images eligible for Garbage Collection, correct?

Comment: @HansPassant - not sure who "We" is in your assertion; however, it is good practise to provide a Finalizer for all code which implements IDisposable so that the code is robust and does not fail if the programmer fails to call Dispose(). Agreed that in this case the Finalizer on Image will be called anyhow.